# Как выбрать элементы в подгруппах groupby, или есть что то изящнее?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, запрос, group-by

Есть два фрейма - ордера с налогами и справочник налога на каждый товар.

Нужно отобрать по каждому коду товара те ордера, в которых значение "налога" выше стандартного, взятого из "справочника".

Вот код:

```
import pandas as pd


def marker(g, epsilon):
    """Mark."""
    g = g.query("fee + fee_preview < -@epsilon")
    return g


df_orders = pd.DataFrame({
    "order_id": list(range(1, 14)),
    "sku": 9 * ["a", ] + 4 * ["b", ],
    "fee_amount": [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1.1, -0.8, -1.1, -2, -2, -2.1, -2.1, -2.1, -4.3],
    "quanty": 7 * [1, ] + 2 * [2, ] + 3 * [1, ] + [2, ],
})

print(df_orders)

df_fee = pd.DataFrame({
    "fee": [1, 0.8, 2.1, 4.3],
    "sku": ["a", "d", "b", "g"],
})

print(df_fee)


df_orders["fee"] = df_orders["fee_amount"] / df_orders["quanty"]

df = df_orders.join(df_fee.set_index("sku"), on="sku", rsuffix="_preview")

dd = df.groupby("sku").apply(marker, 0.005)
print(dd)
```

Все отрабатывает, вот результат:

```
        order_id sku  fee_amount  quanty
0          1   a        -1.0       1
1          2   a        -1.0       1
2          3   a        -1.0       1
3          4   a        -1.0       1
4          5   a        -1.1       1
5          6   a        -0.8       1
6          7   a        -1.1       1
7          8   a        -2.0       2
8          9   a        -2.0       2
9         10   b        -2.1       1
10        11   b        -2.1       1
11        12   b        -2.1       1
12        13   b        -4.3       2
   fee sku
0  1.0   a
1  0.8   d
2  2.1   b
3  4.3   g
        order_id sku  fee_amount  quanty   fee  fee_preview
sku                                                        
a   4          5   a        -1.1       1 -1.10          1.0
    6          7   a        -1.1       1 -1.10          1.0
b   12        13   b        -4.3       2 -2.15          2.1
```

Но меня смущает операция `.join()`, раздувающая промежуточный фрейм.

Нет ли чего то "более SQL" подобного, или другого решения, боле экономно использующего память?

Comment: Первое, что приходит в голову, это передать справочник в функцию *marker* в качестве параметра. Но тогда как то внутри нее нужно знать значение *sku*, по которому отобрана группа... Как внутри *marker* получить конкретное значение параметра, по которому сделан *groupby*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я нашел решение.  Вот как выглядит функция обработки группы:

```
def mark(g, epsilon, df_fee):
    """Select."""
    fee_preview = df_fee[df_fee.sku == g.sku.unique()[0]].fee.values[0]  # 1
    g = g.query("fee + @fee_preview < -@epsilon")                        # 2
    g["fee_preview"] = fee_preview                                       # 3
    return g
```

#1  -  определяем *sku*  группы
#2  -  фильтрация нужных строк, почти без изменения как в исходном варианте
#3  -  добавляем в группу столбец, в котором добавлен контрольный "налог" *fee*

и вызов теперь без *join*. Вместо

```
df = df_orders.join(df_fee.set_index("sku"), on="sku", rsuffix="_preview")
dd = df.groupby("sku").apply(marker, 0.005)
```

Теперь:

```
dd =  df_orders.groupby("sku").apply(select_0, 0.005, df_fee)
```

Лишний промежуточный фрейм  ***df*** "уволен"...
Что интересно, столбец, добавляется на уровне каждой группы и потом объединяется *pandas groupby* автоматически. Рад, что так можно.

Answer (score 3):

Львиная доля методов и функций в Pandas возвращают новый созданный результирующий DataFrame. Некоторые функции поддерживают параметр `inplace=True` - замену DataFrame "на месте" с экономией памяти. Но сами разработчики Pandas [считают эту, казалось бы, полезную фичу злом и хотят от нее избавиться в будущих версиях.](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16529)

Поэтому ваше решение вполне нормальное.

В том случае если вам нужно добавить только один новый столбец, объединяя по другому столбцу, можно воспользоваться методом [Series.map()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df_orders["fee_preview"] = df_orders["sku"].map(df_fee.set_index("sku")["fee"])
```

но в любом случае лучше сравнить производительность обоих методов на немаленьких датасетах...

Comment: вообще то я хотел получить результат как бы применяя групбай, но БЕЗ *join* вообще.   Я написал примечание к вопросу. А за метод - благодарю, не знал..

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, скорее всего можно переместить эту логику в функцию, но подозреваю, что это будет менее эффективно, т.к. вам придется делать подобную операцию в функции для каждой группы

Comment: Я написал ответ в стиле того что я хотел...